# How many integer points on an elliptic curve?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

Let $Q$ denote the rational numbers, let $Z$ the integers and  let $a\neq b$ be two given positive numbers with $a^2/b^2\in Q$. For any given  $m,n\in Z^+$ with $(m,n)\neq (0,0)$, consider the equation in $Z\times Z$ given by 
$$
a^2k^2+b^2l^2=a^2m^2+b^2n^2. \quad \tag{1}
$$
Clearly, this equation has the solution $(k,l)=(\pm m,\pm n)$. It has just the trivial solution  $(k,l)=(\pm m,\pm n)$? The question is to ask how many solutions do we have for equation (1)? Can we count them? To relate this to our title, we write (1) as 
$$
\frac{k^2}{m^2+\frac{b^2}{a^2}n^2}+\frac{l^2}{n^2+\frac{a^2}{b^2}m^2}=1.\quad \tag{2}
$$
Now, the question becomes how many integer points on the ellipse given by (2)? We here note that, when $a=b$, (1) reduces to 
$$
k^2+l^2=m^2+n^2,\quad \tag{3}.
$$
By Fermat theorem on sums of two squares, the number of solutions to (3) can be counted exactly. Thus, (1) or (2) is sort of generalization of (3). Finally, when $a^2/b^2\not\in Q$, it is easy to see that (1) just has the trivial solution  $(k,l)=(\pm m,\pm n)$ for any given $m,n\in Z^+$. Thank you!

Comment: Dear teh: an ellipse is not the same thing as an elliptic curve!